# Как работает E2EE?

Tags: openssl

почитал про E2EE и задумался, вот есть пользователи A и B, Условные Alex и John, каждый сгенерировал свою пару приватный/публичный ключ и отправил друг другу публичные ключи, и вдруг сторона A(Alex) решила зашифровать сообщение и отправить его стороне B(John), они зашифровала их со своей парой ключей и отправила, но как его расшифрует сторона B(John) без приватного ключа стороны A(Alex)? Я серьезно не могу понять как оно работает, просьба обьяснить. Я считаю что E2EE если и реален, то устроен не так, как его описывают.Иначе RSA же должен был сломаться давно...

Comment: «они зашифровала их со своей парой ключей» — нет, Alex зашифрует сообщение публичным ключом John, а John сможет его расшифровать своим приватным ключом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В асимметричном шифровании есть две функции:

```
encrypt(message, public_key)
decrypt(message, private_key)
```

Как уже сказали в комментах, когда Alex отправляет сообщение John, он шифрует его публичным ключом John:

```
ciphertext = encrypt(alex_message, john_public_key)
```

John когда получает сообщение, расшифровывает своим приватным ключом:

```
text = decrypt(ciphertext, john_private_key)
```

Но на практике такую простую схему не используют, потому что человек-по-средине (Man-In-The-Middle) может перехватить публичные ключи обеих сторон, и отправить им свои, фейковые публичные ключи. Это дает ему возможность читать и подменять все сообщения.

Comment: А как реализовано безопасное шифрование E2EE? Просто я понять не могу, спасибо вам за данный ответ, он вполне понятный. Но интересно было бы узнать про вариант без возможности MITM-Атаки

Comment: @Mightdragon полностью исключить MITM-атаку можно только при личной встрече с собеседником (или каким-то доверенным лицом) и личным обменом ключами во время этой встречи. Потому что при использовании средств связи (любых) не получится заранее узнать, является ли собеседник «на другом конце провода» тем самым настоящим собеседником, а не каким-нибудь злоумышленником

Comment: Жалко. Спасибо большое.